# Correlation between variable in the same column

Tags: r

I have a dataframe df. The challenge is the categorical variables are in the same column and the values are in another column. I need to plot the correlation without transforming the dataset. Here it is

```
   df
   Date             B      C
   2019-09-09     Cat1     2
   2019-09-10     Cat1     3
   2019-09-11     Cat1     5
   2019-09-09     Cat2     7
   2019-09-10     Cat2     9
   2019-09-11     Cat2     10
```

if you observe carefully, i need to plot the correlation between Cat1 and Cat2 for value in column C  against Date. Is there a way? The categories in 2 column could be more than 2. But how do we plot it if the variables are in the same column?

Lets say we have dataframe df like below. In this it is easy to plot

```
   df
   Date               Cat1   Cat2
   2019-09-09          2        7
   2019-09-10          3        9 
   2019-09-11          5        10
```

In this case we can use below code

```
  ggplot(df, aes(x=Cat1, y=Cat2))+geom_point()
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'plot the correlation'?  Do you just want to plot `C` against `Date`, grouped by `B` (in which case your data is in the ideal format for just plugging into `ggplot2`), or do you want to calculate correlation coefficients?

Comment: Not coefficients. Letc say we have 2 column Cat1 and Cat2. We usually plot aes(x=Cat1, y=Cat2) right? In the similar way

Answer (score 2):

It should be pretty easy by using `tidyr` package. See below:

```
library(tidyr)

df <- data.frame(Date = c("2019-09-09","2019-09-10","2019-09-11","2019-09-09","2019-09-10","2019-09-11"),
                         B = c(rep("Cat1",3),rep("Cat2",3)),
                         C = c(2,3,5,7,9,10))

df.tidy <- spread(df, key = B, value = C)

df.tidy

#           Date Cat1 Cat2
#   1 2019-09-09    2    7
#   2 2019-09-10    3    9
#   3 2019-09-11    5   10
```

Comment: I do not want to transform the data. I need to plot like that only

Comment: ggplot aesthetics (such as x and y) must be the same length as the data. So I think you won't be able to make a ggplot with 3 points without modifying your data so it has 3 rows. Not sure why you'd be averse to that, it doesn't actually modify the original data frame object, it just creates a new copy temporarily for ggplot.

Comment: You could omit the data arg and do `with(df, 
  ggplot(mapping = aes(x = C[B == 'Cat1'], y = C[B == 'Cat2'])) +
    geom_point()
)` but that seems harder.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your clarification in the comments, it appears this is what you want.

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(df, aes(x=Date, group = B)) + 
  geom_line(aes(y = C, color = B))
```

You need to specify how the variables are grouped by passing the column with the groups to the group argument. Then pass the y values to the `aes()` function in the `geom_line()` call. You can add color to the lines based on the groups.

Just note that this is not a correlation so your question is misleading.

**EDIT**

To plot the Cat1 against Cat2 without transforming the data is trickier. I do not know how to do this without transforming the data, but since you are adamant that this is not what you want, an alternative is to create a makeshift function where the data is transformed within the function and ggplot is used on the transformed data in the function and the plot is returned. The transformed data is only defined within the scope of the function so it will not be in the global environment

```r
gg_group_point <- function(x, group, values){

  df <- x

  xy_key <- colnames(x[,group, drop = F])

  xy_val <- colnames(x[,values, drop = F])

  df_transformed <- spread(df, key = xy_key, value = xy_val)

  xpos <- colnames(df_transformed[, 2, drop = F])

  ypos <- colnames(df_transformed[, 3, drop = F])

  p <- ggplot(df_transformed, aes_string(x=xpos, y=ypos)) + geom_point()

  return(p)
}
```

Supply the column index of the column with the x and y axis variables to the group argument, and the column with the values to the values argument.

```r
df3 <- df[, c('B', 'Date', 'C')]

gg_group_point(df3, group = 1, values = 3)
```

I've switched the columns around just to be sure this works even when the grouping variable isn't in the 2nd column. The only caveat here is that this only works if you have two variables. Anything more than that then you will require multiple xy plots or possibly a faceted plot.

Comment: nope.What you have plotted is trend. I have edited my question for you. See below sample table. That table is transformed, In that case it is easy plot cat1 and cat2, But in the above table it is difficult

Comment: So you want to plot Cat2 against Cat1? In this case then you won't have the dates, Cat1 will be on the x axis and Cat2 will be on the y axis.

Comment: Yes, But how do we do when the variables are in the same column

Comment: I've edited my answer to give what you want. I do not know how to achieve that plot without transforming the data first, so I've transformed the data within the custom function so that your original data remains the same. I hope this helps.